# X Error of failed request on SSH

Tags: ssh, x11, xforwarding

I'm trying to use xforwarding to run a program on my machine, however I get the error

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXUnsupportedPrivateRequest
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (X_GLXVendorPrivate)
  Serial number of failed request:  24
  Current serial number in output stream:  25
```

I've found [this](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glxencode1.3.pdf), but I still don't understand what this means.

Something that I have noticed is that when I run glxgears over xforwarding, the gears show up but they don't spin.

Could anyone explain what this error means, or point me to some better documentation?